# Textarea resizer overlays modal jquery dialog

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, z-order

In the image below you can see the resizer overlapping the dialog. The model overlay and its dialog are clearly higher in z-order than the textarea, but the textarea's resizer still shows through the top left corner of the dialog.

[image]

Short of hiding the resizer `textarea {resize: none;}` is there another way to get the textarea resizer to behave?

OSX `10.8.5` + Chrome `32.0.1700.77`

***UPDATE*** : *I thought this was css related so in a rev of the fiddle I turned off overflow-y, but it turns out that if I mess with .height() and change the text it reverts to being broken. Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanimal/bn9Vd/4/), it has no css except the inline height value. I believe this is a mac/chrome issue only. I filed a bug w/ Google using Chrome/Settings/Tools.*

Comment: Have you tried adding some CSS that interacts specifically with that resizer?  If your textarea is controlled by javascript and has a class, you can cascade from there and give the resizer a lower z-index

Comment: No, this is just a standard textarea rendered in chrome.

Comment: Would you mind throwing this into a fiddle so we can test and check and try different things?

Comment: Very nice, remember to post your answer when you get it to work.  Your fiddle works on my macs and pcs, but I do not have maverick installed.  I'm going to play around and see whats hapenning

Comment: Check this out. If I mess with .height() and change the text it reverts to being broken, no css except the inline height value.
http://jsfiddle.net/shanimal/bn9Vd/4/